# Calling Class Method in PHP

Tags: php

When to call class method directly?

```
<?php
Class::method();
?>
```

When to call class method after object instatiated?

```
<?php
$object = new Class();
$object->method();
?>
```

What are the differences between both of them?

Comment: 1st one i assume is static method...

Comment: Direct call must be static method?

Comment: You can simply check the [official](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) [document](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for more information.

Comment: Sort of tangential, but explains the difference and what difference the difference makes: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Answer (score 1):

Methods which are defined as static those methods will be called directly.
Like function1 is static so it will be called as

```
A::function1();

class A
{
 public static function function1()
  {
    $a = "Hi";
    return $a;
}

 public function function2()
 {
   $a = "Hi";
   return $a;
}
```

}

Where as second method is not static and it will be called on the object of class A like below

```
$object = new A();

$object->function2();
```

Answer (score 0):

`::` scope resolution operator that is used for direct call static class methods without object

```
Class::method();
```

you can use class variables `$this->...` in this method.

`$object = new Class();` `new` is create object of class and you can also use class variables from `object`
in simple way object is instance of class.

Answer (score 0):

if you are making any class function static then you can access by using scope resolution operator like in 1st case.In case of static function `$this` is not available inside function.

```
<?php
      class Product
      {

        public static function method()  //static function
        {
            echo "static function" ;
        }
      }

      Product::method();   // we can make direct call
    ?>
```

while in 2nd case object is created and we are accessing class methods through objects.

```
$object = new Class();
$object->method();
```